# Default values of axes width and height of plots with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How does `pgfplots` determine the default size (width and height) of a plot particularly the box defined by axes?

I have checked one of the plots that I generated with default values of pgfplots using trial-and-error and draw the line:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (6.86,5.69);
```

It seems like, the inner box is approximately 6.86cm by 5.69cm. Or 194.457pt by 161.291pt.

[image]

Comment: You can specify the width and height of the box using `scale only axis` key, and you can get the default width and height using `\axisdefaultwidth` and `\axisdefaultheight`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can read in the [PGFPlots Manual, Section 4.10.1, page 292 (v1.15)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=292)

- the default `width` is set by `\axisdefaultwidth` macro, and it is preset to
  `240pt`
- the default `height` is set by `\axisdefaultheight` macro, and it is
  preset to `207pt`

Also, tick labels, axis labels and the title  has a fixed dimension of `45pt`. See [PGFPlots Manual, Section 4.10.1, page 291 (v1.15)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=291).

This means that the box itself would have dimensions of `195pt` and `162pt`, which is very near the values that you measured yourself.

Comment: Stefan I proposed some additions from the comment of @JohnKormylo. I will accept your answer after it is reviewed.