Why do x and y axes not have the same default format using minor tick num?
As written, I would think the MWE below would produce identically labeled x and y axes, but it does not. The y-axis is missing half of its labels and their corresponding major tick marks. Uncommenting the xtick = and ytick = lines fixes this. I cannot find anything in the documentation about this. Searching this site turns up this answer but that situation involves floating point error and I don't think that's the problem here. Is this a bug or am I just missing something? I have not noticed this problem before.
My MWE:
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      title = {Plot of \( y \) vs.\@ \( x \)},
      xlabel = {x label},
      ylabel = {y label},
      xmin = 0,
      xmax = 6,
      %xtick = {0,...,6},
      ymin = 0,
      ymax = 6,
      %ytick = {0,...,6},
      minor tick num = 1,
    ]%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output:


The width and height of the plot are not equal. You can set them to the same value or use axis equal image (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61040/316068).

Well that worked. I'm quite surprised that this is the default design, but I suppose there is a reason for it. If you make that an answer I will accept it.

By default the size of pgfplots graphs is 240x207 pt (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380539/316068): width and height are not equal; that's why you get different ticks gaps on the x and y axes.
To get the same spacing on both axes, use width=207pt, height=240pt, or best use axis equal image:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      title = {Plot of \( y \) vs.\@ \( x \)},
      xlabel = {x label},
      ylabel = {y label},
      xmin = 0,
      xmax = 6,
      %xtick = {0,...,6},
      ymin = 0,
      ymax = 6,
      %ytick = {0,...,6},
      minor tick num = 1,
      axis equal image
    ]%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I never would have thought, or known, to look for this in the docs.
